# Manual bootstrapping of aurelia app with aurelia-cli

Tags: bootstrapping, aurelia

I'd like to embed my Aurelia App into the resources folder of my Spring Boot App and bootstap/enhance the page manually. The Aurelia bundle is generated with aurelia-cli. In the docs http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/app-configuration-and-startup/4 are examples for JSPM and webpack skeletons. How do I achieve manual bootstapping/progressive enhancement with aurelia-cli?

How should my main.js look like? Where should I include my app-bundle.js and vendor-bundle.js?

**Edit:**
I achieved a working example by including something like this:

```
<div aurelia-app="main">
 <script data-main="aurelia-bootstrapper" src="path-to-resources/vendor-bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="path-to-resources/app-bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
```

But is it possible to include the scripts in lets say in `<head>` and enhance the `<div aurelia-app="main">` on DOMContentLoaded event?

Comment: You should actually add your 3rd party app to the `aurelia.json` file.  Preferably it would go in the `dependencies` section below all of the `aurelia-*` dependencies, but if you have difficulty it could also go in the `prepend` section.

Comment: @LStarky Thanks for your response. I try to make myself more cear. I have an index.html page with non-aurelia content on it and one tag of this page should be my aurelia-app. And I want to bootstrap this app manually. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I manually bootstraped an aurelia-cli app like this.
Here I use a polyfill service via the first script tag. This script runs and downloads missing polyfills for the browser. After that it calls a callback function. This callback function adds the aurelia vendor-bundle script.

```
<body aurelia-app="main" class="sharry not-selectable no-tap-highlight-color">
<div class="app-loding-container">
    <img src="/img/logo/sharry_tv_b.png" alt="sharry logo">
</div>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=HTMLPictureElement,Intl&callback=polyfillsAreLoaded" defer async></script>
<script>
    function polyfillsAreLoaded() {
        var aureliaScript = document.createElement('script');
        aureliaScript.setAttribute('src', '/scripts/vendor-bundle.js');
        aureliaScript.setAttribute('data-main', 'aurelia-bootstrapper');
        document.body.appendChild(aureliaScript);
    }
</script>
```